# Matomo tag manager implementation in Vue

Tags: vue.js, matomo

I am using the Vue plugin for Matomo which is found here: https://github.com/AmazingDreams/vue-matomo

I imported the VueMatomo plugin in my main.js entry file like so:

```
import VueMatomo from 'vue-matomo';
```

Then, I assign the VueMatomo as a global method in my main.js file like so:

```
Vue.use(VueMatomo, {
  // Configure your matomo server and site
  host: 'https://matomo.example.com', 
  siteId: 1, 

  // Enables link tracking on regular links. Note that this won't
  // work for routing links (ie. internal Vue router links)
  // Default: true
  enableLinkTracking: true,

  // Require consent before sending tracking information to matomo
  // Default: false
  requireConsent: false,

  // Whether to track the initial page view
  // Default: true
  trackInitialView: true,

  // Changes the default .js and .php endpoint's filename
  // Default: 'piwik'
  trackerFileName: 'piwik',

  // Whether or not to log debug information
  // Default: false
  debug: false
});
```

How do I implement tags within this plugin?  Would I just set the trackerUrl to my container url like this:

```
// Overrides the autogenerated tracker endpoint entirely
// Default: undefined
trackerUrl: 'https://mycontainer.js'
```

Also how do I send custom data. For example:

```
'user':{        
    'role':'consumer', 
    'type':'purchaser'
}
```

edit: In the Matomo tag manager documentation it says to put this in the head tag.

```
<!-- MTM -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var _mtm = _mtm || [];
_mtm.push({'mtm.startTime': (new Date().getTime()), 'event': 'mtm.Start'});
var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
g.type='text/javascript'; g.async=true; g.defer=true; g.src='https://mycontainer.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
</script>
<!-- End MTM -->
```

So is that still required with the vue-matomo plugin or can you put

```
g.src='https://mycontainer.js'
```

somewhere else?

Comment: Have you figure out how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Under the hood, the `Vue Plugin` simply exposes to you the `Matomo tracking client SDK`. You can call any of the native SDK functions [listed in their SDK on their website](https://developer.matomo.org/guides/tracking-javascript-guide) by going through `this.$matomo`.

You can actually see that they do this in the source code:

```
const Matomo = MatomoJS.getTracker(trackerEndpoint, siteId)

// Assign matomo to Vue
Vue.prototype.$piwik = Matomo
Vue.prototype.$matomo = Matomo
```

Where `MatomoJS` is resolved through `import Matomojs from './matomo'` which is just a `flat javascript file` that packaged their public SDK.

Comment: Okay, I figured out how to send more data using _paq.push. But I still don't understand how to implement the container.

Comment: @Josh I have no idea what the idea or purpose of the container is. I just know how the Matomo integration works. Sorry.